# How to ultra compress huge size file in macOS

Tags: compression

I am using macOS, and I need to extremely reduce a .iso file size from 11 GB to some small bytes.
Do you guys have an idea on how to do that in macOS? I tried many compression apps but they reduced only 1 MB out of the total size, which is totally unuseful in my case.
Please help me.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Why are you trying to reduce the size by such a large amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use good zipping software's for mac available to make good  possible compression

**KGB Archiver** provides best compression for MAC but not as what you want

**What you say 11 GB to some bytes if you do even which is impossible the data will become corrupted**

Its not possible clearly

Many people in Internet publish very big files in very small sizes to attract people and download by deceiving ads surveys which is total fraud

Answer (score 1):

The compression ratio highly depends on the data you are trying to compress.
For instance, if you have a big text file filled with the word `test`, you can easily compress it from 10GB to a few MB, as the data is highly redundant.
However if you want to compress a 10GB movie, in most cases the best you can do is reducing the size by a few MB no matter how good the software is or how powerful your computer is.
There's no major differences between different compression softwares,  if one software cannot reduce the size of the file much, then it's pretty much pointless to try different softwares.